# mongodump only dumps few collections when run from script, compete database if run from terminal;

Tags: bash, mongodb

I have a script that dumps the db and copies it to S3. This is the crontab entry that calls the script:

`*/1 * * * * /root/scripts/backupDB.sh`

backupDB.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/

date_now=`date +%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M`
dir_name="db_backup"
tar_name="db_backup_${date_now}.tar.gz"
file_name="${dir_name}/${tar_name}"

if [ -z "$dir_name" ]; then
    mkdir $dir_name
fi

log() {
    echo $1
    echo $1 >> ${HOME}/tmp/mybackup.log
}

do_cleanup(){
    rm -rf db_backup* 
    log 'cleaning up....'
}

do_backup(){
    log 'Starting the backup' && \
    /usr/bin/mongodump -o ${HOME}/${dir_name} && \
    log 'Data dump created'
    /bin/tar -cjf ${HOME}/${tar_name} ${HOME}/${dir_name} && \
    log 'Created archive'

    log 'saving the backup archive in amazon S3' && \
    /usr/bin/s3cmd put --acl-private ${HOME}/${tar_name} s3://bucket/db-backups/${tar_name} && \
    log 'data backup saved in amazon s3'
}


do_backup && do_cleanup
```

If run through the terminal, the same script dumps all the databases. If run through cron, only dumps a few collections of each database. The mongodb log is pasted [here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/561874/) It shows nothing weird. You can see connections being made at the beginning of every minute, correspond to the crontab entry that calls the script. But it also shows that the connection is ended immediately. What might be the problem?

Comment: In your shell, does the folder `db_backup/` already exist? Your script only attempts the `mkdir` when `$dir_name` is empty(!!). Also, try adding `set -x` or `set -v` to your script. Maybe a `trap` on `ERROR` too.

Comment: @bobbogo yes, mongodump creates the folder `db_backup`. That is why I have not tested for existence.

Comment: can you show a dump of `${HOME}/tmp/mybackup.log`?

Comment: @Shawn http://paste.ubuntu.com/564404/ Btw, I have stopped the script on this server, and am executing this script on a CentOS server, where it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long does the script take to run?

Since you're running it from cron rather frequently, there's always a worry that the next instance might start before the first has finished leading to all sorts of issues with the output depending on what the script does.

You'll want to implement [some form of locking](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/mutex) to prevent concurrent runs.

Comment: I decreased the frequency to 3 minutes from 1. Running the entire script takes just over a minute. Now that will make sure that there is no locking.

Comment: Does that solve the problem? What happens when your data grows or when the system is running on high load and the script takes longer to run? IMHO, I still think it's worth putting in place locking.

Comment: Thats true. I should look into it. BTW, the script works fine on CentOS. It wasnt working on Debian.